# Missing APIs in Google Tasks API Java library

Tags: java, android, api, task

I'm trying to write a Tasks app for Android, using the v1.3 library here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/com/google/?repo=mavenrepo&r=07a469e9e478c9e13e375c4d569436d4e261c59c#google%2Fapis%2Fgoogle-api-services-tasks%2Fv1-1.3.0-beta

As per the [Javadoc](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/tasks/v1/index.html), the TaskList class has a getUpdated() API, returning the last-modification time of the list.  However, it's missing in the library and I need this API.  Any reason why it's missing and how I can get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API was added in v1.6 of the library. Not sure why it was missing before.